# Expression for the awkward situation when you see an acquaintance and debate whether to acknowledge their presence

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any expression in English that refers to the situation when someone who is just an acquaintance (not a close friend) happens to be present around you at a social gathering (be it at a house party, a club  ...), and you are debating whether to show them that you have seen them out of being shy or to avoid an awkward greeting?

I'm seeking anything that fits the bill, whether it's a single word, or a phrase.

Comment: Please [include a sample sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) so we can get a better sense of the kind of word you're looking for. (I've also changed your second tag to "phrase-requests", in accordance with the guidance for those tags.)

Comment: *in a quandary*

Answer (score -1):

Broadly no, there is not… if for no other reason then simply because '…out of being shy…' said all that was needed. FYI, '… being shy…' encompasses 'to avoid an awkward greeting'

If not to 'Shyness' you might look to 'Cowardice/ Doubt/ Guilt/ Hesitation/ Uncertainty'; even some kind of 'shame' might fit the bill but still, what you describe is not the situation in which you find yourself, but your slightly unusual reaction to it.

Your idea of '… just an acquaintance (not a close friend)…' might be different from mine or any other's and the point is where you draw the line, and why you feel it matters.

In every territory of the English-speaking world - prolly everywhere else, too - you're expected to greet everyone you've met before, however slight that acquaintance is.

'To greet' might mean nothing more than 'Hey… I hope you're well…' as you pass by, clearly not intent on stopping to chat.

'To greet' might even mean nothing more than a nod without words, though preferably with a smile that doesn't look too false.

Comment: "You're expected to greet everyone you've met before"--huh? If you're at (say) a big party and someone you half-know shows up, you're not obligated to go over and greet them.

Comment: Thanks Alphabet. Which part of '… nothing more than a nod without words, though preferably with a smile that doesn't look too false' do you not accept?